# Error when removing '::Base' from ActionController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, radix, actioncontroller

I'm writing a rails application, and in this one controller I need to specify the layout to render due to inheriting from `ActionController::Base`.  In some of my other controllers I just have ActionController and it automatically uses the application layout.  Whenever I remove the `::Base`, I get the following message when accessing the page `superclass must be a Class (Module given)`.

Why does inheriting from `ActionController::Base` in this controller matter, but not in the others?

Answer (score 2):

To directly answer your question `ActionController` is not a controller class, it's a namespacing module that powers the entire controller stack. You would not interact with the `ActionController` module during typical Rails development. `ActionController::Base` is actually the class that controllers inherit from. This is why you can't inherit from `ActionController`.

But I think there are two controllers in play here. `ActionController::Base` and `ApplicationController`. I think you might be mistaking `ApplicationController` for being `ActionController` without the `::Base`.

`ActionController::Base` is the main controller class where all of your Rails functionality comes from. `ApplicationController` is a generalized controller that you can add methods to and have all of your other Rails controllers inherit from.

You could do the following to use a different layout in one of your controllers:

```
class AuthenticationController < ApplicationController
  layout 'authentication'
end
```

You can either use the `AuthenticationController` directly, or have new controllers inherit from `AuthenticationController`.

Answer (score 0):

Your controllers should inherit from `ApplicationController`. This will allow them to automatically render the application layout. ApplicationController extends ActionController::Base.